# Restore VM to factory settings - sort of

Tags: virtual-machine

I got a VirtualBox VM from a friend with Windows 7 Ultimate on it. I would like to set it to factory settings (sort of) without deleting the installed programs and personal files. Anything else should be reset, like username, network settings etc. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: Manually.

There's no quick button to press which will do this. Its not like a mobile phone. You'll have to manually edit the username, network settings etc, and you'll always have the risk that you forgot to alter something. It therefor is much easier to create a new VM and install windows from scratch. This means you will have to install the programs again too and copy over the personal files.

You can create a new userprofile which is probably half of the work already, then after moving the files out of the old profiles that you want to keep, delete that old profile. Don't forget to double check if your new user has administrative rights though.

Answer (score 0):

For manual consider:

- User name: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19834.how-to-rename-a-windows-7-user-account-and-related-profile-folder.aspx
- Computer name: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/change-your-computer-name-in-windows-vista/
- Personalisation from MS Office (Open a Office Programme: "File"->"Options")
- Reset Browsers